# Symfony3 - Why tests are no longer in the bundles now?

Tags: architecture, symfony

I'm upgrading my project from Symfony2 to Symfony3, and I choose the new directory structure. So I'm wondering why tests are no longer located in the bundles but in a new `tests/` root directory ? So when someone creates a bundle under Symfony3 and want to externalize it, there will be no tests inside ?

I thought that the goal of bundles was to be fully independent, will it be the case with this new architecture ?

Comment: Reference : http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html

Comment: Sometimes I think the Symfony developers just get bored.  The idea is that consumers of bundles don't really need the tests so by moving the tests to their own directory we can save several microseconds of valuable down load time.  I myself just store tests in the same folder as the things they test.  Maintaining parallel directory structures gets old real fast.

Comment: So composer put this path only in a dev classloading environment and exclude that files from prod env

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you generate a bundle with the Symfony command

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

There is this question :

> Are you sharing this schedule we bundle across multiple applications
>   [no]:

If you put yes, the folder of the structure is different from a conventional bundle and the test file is present in this bundle.

I assume that the architecture in shared or private bundle bundle are different and shared bundle remains completly independent.

I hope that helps you

Comment: Not really.  The question is about the new 'tests' directory, not the existing 'Tests'.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I'm not explicit. I believe that new 'Tests' is the same folder that existing 'Test' when we outsource a bundle.